# How to call a class from Main() method?

Tags: c#

I am currently working on the project listed below. So far I am having trouble accessing my class from my program. I'm not sure if it's something that I am missing or if I'm just in over my head. I will include the code I have came up with so far.

You will be graded on:

- Your code must compile. If your code has a compile error and does not run, you will not receive a passing score.
- Your code must follow the guidelines provided. For example: Your final code must contain 3 classes. If all your code is done from within the main() with a series of WriteLine() methods, you will not do well.

Waikiki Hilton Beach Rentals Application:

You will be creating a program for Waikiki Hilton Beach Rentals. Here guests of the Hilton can rent beach equipment such as flotation rafts, snorkel gear, chairs, umbrellas and paddle boats.

Your application will get the guest name, items rented, qty of each item rented and total minutes rented. A guest can rent as many items as they would like, and multiple quantities. You can assume that all items are rented for the same time frame. So a guest can rent 2 chairs, and snorkel gear – but all for 65 minutes. (not chairs for 15, and the snorkel gear for 45 for example)

You will be creating three classes, the BeachRentalsApp  which will be the entry point of the program,  a Rental  class which you will be using to create rental objects, and a guestclass which holds the guest information.

BeachRentalsApp – where the program begins. This should create a guest object. Your guest object  holds the guest name, contract number and an array of Rental  objects. The app should display a welcome message, and then get the guest info as well as the rental info. All of the info displayed and gathered in the main() method should be called from methods within the BeachRentalsApp class.

Contains the following methods:

- main() – instantiates a Guest object, and as many Rental objects as required. Rental objects are then stored in an array data element in the Guest object ie itemsRented[ ]. The main method should call methods to get input and display data. Methods to call in this class should include:
- Display a welcome message
- Get the guest name
- Get the contract number
- Gets minutes rented – a guest has to rent for a minimum of an hour and no more than 8 hours.
- Gets the item to rent and qty
- displays the static array from the Rental Class
- gets the qty and item to rent
- Displays the final rental info:
- Guest name
- For each item: item rented, total cost of rental (price of item * rental period)
- A final total of all items rented

Guest – A class that holds guest info

Properties:

- Guest Name
- Contract Number (ie K168)
- # Hours rented
- # Minutes rented
- Items Rented (an array of rental objects)

Constructors as appropriate: requires a minimum of guest name to instantiate a guest object.

Methods:

- Sets the contract Number. If no number is provided, create a random contract number. It should start with the first letter of the customer name, and then a randomly generated additional 4 numbers.
- Accepts the minutes rented and sets the class data fields (# hours rented, # minutes rented) accordingly.

Rental – A class that describes a rental

Constructors as appropriate. Users of this class need a minimum of a rental item to instantiate an object.

Static members:

- an array of the rental items available (such as flotation rafts, snorkel gear, chairs, umbrellas, paddle boats)
- The hourly rate for each of the following is:
- flotation raft – $15
- snorkel gear – $25
- chairs – $8
- umbrella – $10
- paddle boat - $40

Properties:

- item Rented (ie umbrella)
- qty rented (ie 3 umbrellas)
- total rental price (ie umbrella cost $10 * rental period * 3 umbrellas)

Methods

- static method that displays the items available for rental
- calculates total price - calculated in half hour increments. For example. An umbrella costs $8 per hour. If the rental period is 30 minutes, the price is $4. Otherwise the price is $8. So a rental of 75 minutes costs $12. (1 hour is $8 and additional up to 30 minutes is $4) A rental of 45 minutes costs $8.

Code:

```
namespace BeachRentalsApp
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main()
        {

            Welcome();
            string[] RentalList = { "1. Floatation Rafts", "2. Snorkel Gear", "3. Chairs", "4. Umbrellas", "5. Paddle Boat" };

            int LenOfArray = RentalList.Length;
            for (int i = 0; i < LenOfArray; i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(RentalList[i]);

            }
        }

        public static void Welcome()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("******************************************");
            Console.WriteLine("Welcome to Waikiki Hilton Beach Rentals!");
            Console.WriteLine("******************************************");
            Console.WriteLine("                                          ");
            Console.WriteLine("You will be asked to enter your name and ");
            Console.WriteLine("pick the equipment you would like to rent.");
            Console.WriteLine("We hope that you enjoy your stay at Waikiki");
            Console.WriteLine("and look forward to serving you again soon!");
            Console.WriteLine("                                           ");
            Console.WriteLine("Enter your name to start renting Equipment:  ");
            string GName = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.Clear();
            Console.WriteLine("Thank you {0}! Please take a look at equipment selection!", GName);
        }
    }

    class Rentals
    {
        public int FloatationPrice = 15;
        public int SnorkelPrice = 25;
        public int ChairPrice = 8;
        public int UmbrellaPrice = 10;
        public int PaddlePrice = 40;
        public int RentTime = 65;

        public Rentals()
        {
            string[] RentalSelection = new string[5];
            RentalSelection[0] = "";
            RentalSelection[1] = "";
            RentalSelection[2] = "";
            RentalSelection[3] = "";
            RentalSelection[4] = "";
            Console.Write("Which equipment would you like to rent?");
            RentalSelection[0] = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.Write("Would you like to rent more items?");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome, your question is way too long and poorly formatted, maximize your chances of getting an answer by improving its content.

Comment: The Stack Overflow question editor is quite rich.  You can create lists (including multilevel lists), highlight things (with italics and bold), etc.  If you make your question readable, there's a much higher likelihood that someone will read it.

Comment: Following what was already mentioned, nothing between `You will be graded on` and where the code starts is required for this question

Comment: In general, a class represents a class of objects.  For example, consider something you can rent.  It has a name, a price per minute, a price per hour, etc.  Then you create instances of the class by constructing/initializing instances.  Once you have an instance, you can call methods on it (for example, `Rent`).  You could create one instance per type of rentable thing, or you could create a class hierarchy (a RentableThing abstract base class, and then specific subclasses for each kind of rentable thing).  Hopefully you professor has showed you some of this

Comment: I have just formatted your question so you can see what good formatting is and how to do it (edit the question to see the syntax), that said, it's still way too long as @CamiloTerevinto mentioned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Here's how you could do that:**

[image]

Code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace BeachRentalsApp
{
    internal static class Program
    {
        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Welcome!");

            string name;

            while (true)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Enter your name:");

                name = Console.ReadLine();

                if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(name))
                    break;
            }

            Console.WriteLine("Enter your contract number or press Enter to generate one:");

            var contract = Console.ReadLine();

            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(contract))
            {
                contract = $"{name[0]}{new Random().Next(1000, 10000)}";
                Console.WriteLine($"Generated the following contract number: {contract}");
            }

            var minutes = GetNumber("For how long? (minutes, between 1 and 8 hours):", 60, 60 * 8);

            Console.WriteLine("We have the following items available:");

            var items = Rentals.Items;

            for (var i = 0; i < items.Length; i++)
            {
                var item = items[i];
                Console.WriteLine($"{i + 1}. {item.Name} ({item.Price:C})");
            }

            var dictionary = new Dictionary<Item, Rental>();

            while (true)
            {
                var index = GetNumber("Choose an item or 0 to complete your order:", 0, items.Length);
                if (index == 0)
                    break;

                var quantity = GetNumber("Enter quantity:", 1, 9999);

                var item = items[index - 1];

                if (dictionary.ContainsKey(item))
                {
                    dictionary[item].Duration = minutes;
                    dictionary[item].Quantity += quantity;
                }
                else
                {
                    var rental = new Rental
                    {
                        Duration = minutes,
                        Quantity = quantity
                    };
                    dictionary.Add(item, rental);
                }
            }

            Console.WriteLine();

            var total = 0.0m;

            Console.WriteLine("Here's your bill :)");
            Console.WriteLine();

            foreach (var pair in dictionary)
            {
                var itemName = pair.Key.Name;
                var itemQuantity = pair.Value.Quantity;
                var itemDuration = pair.Value.Duration;
                var itemPrice = pair.Key.Price;
                var itemTotal = Math.Ceiling(itemDuration / 60.0m) * itemPrice * itemQuantity;
                Console.WriteLine($"{itemName}:");
                Console.WriteLine($"\tQuantity = {itemQuantity}");
                Console.WriteLine($"\tDuration = {itemDuration}");
                Console.WriteLine($"\tTotal = {itemTotal:C}");
                Console.WriteLine();
                total += itemTotal;
            }

            Console.WriteLine($"Grand total: {total:C}");

            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.WriteLine("We hope to see you again!");

            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit.");

            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        private static int GetNumber(string message, int min, int max)
        {
            if (message == null)
                throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(message));

            while (true)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(message);

                if (int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out var number) && number >= min && number <= max)
                    return number;
            }
        }
    }

    public class Item
    {
        public Item(string name, decimal price)
        {
            if (price <= 0.0m)
                throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(price));

            Name = name ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(name));
            Price = price;
        }

        public string Name { get; }

        public decimal Price { get; }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return $"{nameof(Name)}: {Name}, {nameof(Price)}: {Price:C}";
        }

        #region Equality members

        private bool Equals(Item other)
        {
            return string.Equals(Name, other.Name);
        }

        public override bool Equals(object obj)
        {
            if (ReferenceEquals(null, obj))
                return false;
            if (ReferenceEquals(this, obj))
                return true;
            if (obj.GetType() != GetType())
                return false;

            return Equals((Item) obj);
        }

        public override int GetHashCode()
        {
            return Name.GetHashCode();
        }

        #endregion
    }

    public class Rental
    {
        public int Duration { get; set; }

        public int Quantity { get; set; }
    }

    public static class Rentals
    {
        public static Item[] Items { get; } =
        {
            new Item("Flotation Raft", 15.0m),
            new Item("Snorkel Gear", 25.0m)
        };
    }
}
```

**Next steps:**

- study the code by debugging it, step-through with <kbd>F11</kbd>
- check the documentation with <kbd>F1</kbd>
- understand what's going on
- adjust it as needed

There are numerous way to achieve the same result, this one does:

- check for correct input
- allow to exit the buying loop using <kbd>0</kbd>

I deliberately did not make it 1:1 so you'll have to understand it first and modify it, it'd be obvious that you didn't find it by yourself otherwise :)

Also, tell your teacher he's stupid, these kind of exercises only makes you hate coding even more!

Answer (score 0):

Well an object is a class that contains descriptive data about a certain item. For example a Guest object will have things like name, the data structure containing their rental list.. etc.

So, where you should start is by creating the Guest object as defined by the assignment and the Rental object as defined by the assignment.

Assuming you have created your objects, you need to access them, how you do this is by:

```
public static void Main()
        {

            Welcome(); // Get rid of getting their name in welcome, do it here
            Console.WriteLine("Guest name");  
            String guestName = Console.readLine(); 
            String guestContractNumber = Console.readLine();
            if (guestContractNumber.equals("")
            {
// Generate a random guestContract number if they didn't provide one
            }
            // The guest object is created below.
            Guest guest = new Guest(guestName, guestContractNumber);                                                                        
            // The rental object is supposed to have the rental types
            Rental rental = new Rental();

        }
```

I hope this may get you on the right track. To create an object (a class) you need to:

```
TestClass testClass = new TestClass();
```

and now you can access the object:

```
 testClass.doSomething();
```

If you need to be able to access data from a class before you create it, you can use
the static keyword before the data member:

```
class TestClass
{
public static String testString = "Rental items 1... 2..etc";
}
```

and now you can just do:

```
TestClass.testString
```

to get the value of the testString.

If you need anymore help I will try to help, good luck.